# Node.js -> Updating one field caused lose the other fields

Tags: node.js

So I am creating a backend for React project, and in there I'm filling out a form to create a page. For now, I have a dummy array of pages that looks like this;

```
const PAGES = [
  {
    id: "p1",
    name: "Webinar Butique",
    tema: "Boho",
    area: "Hardware Store",
    type: "Basic",
    imageUrl: "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/U72Aoxuv5d8/maxresdefault.jpg",
    creator: "u1",
  },
];
```

Properties are; `"name", "type", "area", "tema"`

In the backend, I created a middleware called **createPage** to make a post request on `router.post("/api/pages", pagesController.createPage)`

**createPage**

```
const createPage = (req, res, next) => {
  const { name, tema, type, area, creator } = req.body;
  // instead of doing -> const name = req.body.name for each of them use {}

  const createdPage = {
    id: uuidv4(),
    name,
    tema,
    type,
    area,
    creator,
  };

  PAGES.push(createdPage); // unshift(createdPage)

  res.status(201).json({ page: createdPage }); // 201 - sucessfully created in the server
};
```

For the **updatePageById**

```
const updatePageById = (req, res, next) => {
  //const stores the address of the object and not the object it self
  const { name, tema, type, area } = req.body;
  const pageId = req.params.pid;

  const updatedPage = { ...PAGES.find((p) => p.id === pageId) };
  const pageIndex = PAGES.findIndex((p) => p.id === pageId);

  updatedPage.name = name;
  updatedPage.type = type;
  updatedPage.area = area;
  updatedPage.tema = tema;

  // replace the old object at that index with the new updatedPage
  PAGES[pageIndex] = updatedPage

  res.status(201).json({page: updatedPage})
};
```

My question is, let's say, the user wants to change only the `"name"` property and leaves the others as it was.

I tried on Postman, **patch** to `http://localhost:8080/api/pages/p1`

```
{
    "name": "new butique"
}
```

But the problem is that when I request a **get** `http://localhost:8080/api/pages/p1` it deletes the field of the other that is not updated (in this case, type,area,tema)

I am already copying existed array doing `const updatedPage = { ...PAGES.find((p) => p.id === pageId) };` but losing them anyway.

In which way I can follow not lose these fields when the user updates only one field, instead of all the requested body?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your function you are telling it to update every value, even if there isnt one:

```
// This part of the function is causing you issues
updatedPage.name = name;
updatedPage.type = type;
updatedPage.area = area;
updatedPage.tema = tema;
```

Therefor your request of:

```
{
    "name": "new butique"
}
```

Will only have a value for `name` and set the rest of the properties to `undefined`. When you overwrite the previous item in `PAGES` it will have the new property but also all the properties with undefined as their values

Before you set the property to a new value, check that the property is present in the incoming request, if it is not then dont update it.

```js
const updatePageById = (req, res, next) => {
  //const stores the address of the object and not the object it self
  const { name, tema, type, area } = req.body;
  const pageId = req.params.pid;

  const updatedPage = { ...PAGES.find((p) => p.id === pageId) };
  const pageIndex = PAGES.findIndex((p) => p.id === pageId);
  
  // only update if the property exists on the request
  if (name) updatedPage.name = name;
  if (type) updatedPage.type = type;
  if (area) updatedPage.area = area;
  if (tema) updatedPage.tema = tema;

  // replace the old object at that index with the new updatedPage
  PAGES[pageIndex] = updatedPage

  res.status(201).json({page: updatedPage})
};
```

Otherwise you can setup a new route for a `PATCH` request. This route would look similar in that if the request has the property, change it; if it does not: dont change it.

Comment: thank you so much! I was trying to make a if statement but could think of just the ```if (propertyName)``` lol.